# Escape the colon from a command so it's not render like a label in batch files

Tags: batch-file, deployment, automation, angular-cli, github-pages

I'll make a bat file with goes deploy my site on GitHub pages. The repository is [heinpauwelyn.github.io](https://heinpauwelyn.github.io) and is made with Angular-CLI. To deploy the site I could use this command:

```
ng github-pages:deploy
```

This will place everything on the `gh-pages` branch but it must stand on the `master` branch! I'm developing on the `development` branch.

To automate the proceedings of committing, deploying, checkout `gh-pages`, copy-pasting, checkout `master`, copy-pasting, committing and checkout `development`, I've create this bat file named `deploy.bat`:

```
git status
git add *
git commit -m "deploy"
git pull
git push

ng github-pages:deploy
git checkout gh-pages 

echo "copy all your files in this folder to a temporary folder outside this repository (except these inside the `.gitignore` file)"
pause

rem must be automatic done by using this xcopy . ..\temp

git checkout master

echo "copy all your file form the temporary folder back into the repository"
pause

rem rmdir /s /q .
rem xcopy ..\temp .

git status
git add *
git commit -m "deploy"
git pull
git push

echo "site is deployed!"

git checkout development
```

The code will stop on this line: `ng github-pages:deploy`. I've checked the syntax on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) and have seen that the colon is a label to skip code from a running batch file. I think this colon gives the bug.

My question is now can I escape the colon from the batch file so that it's not longer a label but a command?

---

**Note**

The goal of the batch file is that I just must use one command to deploy my full site. In the `package.json` file of my project, I use this code:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "deploy.bat"
  }
}
```

When the bug will be solved, I just use command below to deploy my site on the `master` branch.

```
npm run deploy
```

Comment: If I have to bet, `ng` is a batch file. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42872282/2861476) can help.

Comment: And in general it is a good idea to enclose parameter strings not consisting of only A-Za-z_ in double quotes. So most likely `call ng.bat "github-pages:deploy"` or `call ng.cmd "github-pages:deploy"` is what you need. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and `call /?` and read the output help pages carefully.

Comment: One more hint: It is also a good idea to call other batch files and executables always with file name __and extension__ and if possible also with full path. Then the batch file does not depend on current values of local environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` on execution. Windows command interpreter must run lots of `filename.*` searches on executing your batch file (and hopefully always finds the right file).

Comment: `:` is called a colon, and it only acts as a label if it's the first character on a line. It can't be used to go to another part of the script without a `call` or a `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the colon that gives the bug but because `ng` is a batch file. Helped answer: [Azure Function / Azure Website Custom Deploy Script Ending Prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538237/azure-function-azure-website-custom-deploy-script-ending-prematurely/42872282#42872282).

After searching and asking this question, I've found the solution that works!

```
git status
git add *
git commit -m "deploy"
git pull
git push

call ng.cmd "github-pages:deploy"

call git checkout master
call git merge origin/gh-pages --allow-unrelated-histories

dployer.exe rem | This is a little executable file I've written (it's just for changing 
            rem | content of some files)

git add *
git commit -m "deploy bug oke"
git pull
git push

git checkout development
```

Thanks to @MCND, @Mofi and @SomethingDark for the comments !